# Elasticsearch remove default fields from search's response body

Tags: search, elasticsearch, compression

Im doing a query that returns like 70k documents (I need all of them, and Im currently using scan & scroll)

What happens is that the response is very large (2 MB and we alredy reduced it from 6 MB). We alredy filtered the fields we needed, and since the query is only called from an API we reduced the name of the properties.

What i can see is that every document in the array "hits" has the following default fields that i really dont need them:

- _index (we only request on one index)
- _type (we only request on one type)
- _id (we alredy have this on a field)
- _score (we are not scoring)

Is there a way to remove them so i can have the following structure:

```
"hits" : [
{
    "_source": {
        ...
    }
},
{
    "_source": {
        ...
    }
}
```

]

Thanks for reading!
I will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_response_filtering) and the `filter_path` parameter, provided you're using ES 1.6 or later.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source'
```

You can even specify the just the fields you want

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source&_source=title,name'
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Is it possible to filter hits.** fields using POST body request?

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov you can definitely use a POST request and have `filter_path` in the query string.

Comment: Thanks I got that. My questions was if it's possible to put filter_path logic within the body? In order to keep URI clean of parameters.

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov Nope, that's not possible.

Comment: Is it further possible to exclude `hits`, and `source` fields and being left out with the pure results?