# ElasticSearch get only document ids, _id field, using search query on index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

For a given query I want to get only the list of `_id` values without getting any other information (without `_source`, `_index`, `_type`, ...).

I noticed that by using `_source` and requesting non-existing fields it will return only minimal data but can I get even less data in return ?
Some answers suggest to use the `hits` part of the response, but I do not want the other info.

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481977/elasticsearch-remove-default-fields-from-searchs-response-body/33482067#33482067 (hint: use `filter_path`)

Comment: Ok looks like it still existing in ES5 which is nice

Comment: Yes, indeed, that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use scroll and scan to get the result list so elasticsearch doesn't have to rank and sort the results.

With the elasticsearch-dsl python lib this can be accomplished by:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

es = Elasticsearch()
s = Search(using=es, index=ES_INDEX, doc_type=DOC_TYPE)

s = s.fields([])  # only get ids, otherwise `fields` takes a list of field names
ids = [h.meta.id for h in s.scan()]
```

Comment: For recent versions: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy The link is outdated.

Comment: just google with the keywords :) and with some luck the page still exists:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: I've tested `s.fields([])` recently, with ES 7.7.1 (last version supported by AWS Elasticsearch Service) running on macOS, and is incorrect; passing `[]` retrieves all the fields, you should pass `False`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use elasticsearch_dsl for python. They have a nice api.

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Document

# don't return any fields, just the metadata
s = s.source(False)
results = list(s)
```

Afterwards you can get the the id with:

```
first_result: Document = results[0]
id: Union[str,int] = first_result.meta.id
```

Here is the official documentation to get some extra information: https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#extra-properties-and-parameters