# Is there an options to filter out the Elasticsearch query response like _shards?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Is there a way to filter out the `_shards` from the Elasticsearch [query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) response?

I am looking for an option like `size` which removes the results from the `hits`, but for telling Elasticsearch that I don't need the `_shards` key.

An alternative would be to use `jq` to [delete](https://gist.github.com/olih/f7437fb6962fb3ee9fe95bda8d2c8fa4#dealing-with-json-objects) certain keys.

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481977/elasticsearch-remove-default-fields-from-searchs-response-body/33482067#33482067 (hint: use `filter_path`)

Comment: Indeed! I voted for a close as duplicate in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filter_path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering)

```
GET index84/_search?filter_path=-_shards
```

(note the `-` prefixing the `_shards`)

or, for example, if only the found items are needed:

```
GET index84/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
```